# Why is the viewport tag changed in Foundation 5.0? No width=device-width?

Tags: zurb-foundation

In Zurb Foundation 4.0, the [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/rails.html) say to include (in a page head):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

In Zurb Foundation 5.0, the [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html) say to use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Notice that the "width=device-width" specification was dropped. Why?

Every responsive design framework that I've seen includes the "width=device-width" specification. What does it do and why did Foundation 5.0 drop it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It got removed due to an internal miscommunication. Having `width=device-width` alone causes zooming on some devices when you switch to landscape mode, something that's fixed by adding `initial-scale=1.0`. Only having `initial-scale=1.0`, however, breaks the viewport on Android.

The downloads should have the correct viewport tag (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`) in the sample `index.html`, and the docs *should* be fixed now, but let us know if you find an error.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know why it is dropped in foundation 5 , may be it is a bug!

It sets the browser’s layout viewport, relative to which CSS declarations such as width: 20% are calculated, to the device width.

(Incidentally, Opera has proposed to port this functionality to full CSS, which all in all seems to be a good idea. But for the moment we’re stuck with the HTML tag.)

Normally the layout viewport takes a width that the vendor has decided is optimal for viewing desktop sites.
By setting the meta viewport to device-width you’re sure that your site’s width is optimised for the device it’s being viewed on.

You can do this also using media queries..

You can read clearly here http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/01/device-width-and-how-not-to-hate-your.html

Comment: Very good explanation and much appreciated. Given the circumstances, I'm marking the answer from the Zurb engineer as accepted, as he confirms it is a bug.